# How to Scroll Up/Down in Andriod Appium using wd driver using Javascript-nodejs?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, android-studio, appium

I am trying to automate an Android APP where I need to scroll down/up the screen using the wd driver using Javascript(NodeJS Automated Testing with WD.js)

I tried using the below locators and it didn't work

```
await driver.scroll(100, 200);
//await driver.execute('mobile: scroll', {direction: 'down'});
//await  driver.execute("mobile: scroll", [{ direction: 'down' }])
```

I am getting the below error:

> Error: [scroll(100,200)] Error response status: 13, UnknownError - An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Selenium error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: invalid path.

Appreciate your inputs and help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, so I just made use of TouchAction that is part of the wd driver:

```
var touchAction = new wd.TouchAction(global.driver)
  .longPress({ x: 0, y: 1000 })
  .moveTo({ x: 0, y: 10 })
  .release();
await touchAction.perform();
```

In the case of 'global.driver' just put the instance of wd that you have.

This works for me for simple scrolling from an absolute point on screen to another.